# I want to use Guardium to capture usernames and roles from SAP HANA and Exadata

Tags: hana

As part of a program to capture local accounts (we generally use AD federated), I want to use Guardium's capabilities to read through a DBMS's security table and capture the information (which is later ingested by another app I have).  Is it as straight forward for SAP Hana and Exedata as it is with Oracle, MS SQL and Postgress?

I am seeking a sql script, that similar to Oracle/MSSQL, would allow me to add a service account to the database -- and have Guardium come along and read the database for the information I am seeking

Answer (score 0):

From the question it’s not clear what information specifically is required here.

In [How to engineer your DB code](https://www.lbreddemann.org/how-to-engineer-your-db-code/) I’ve used a common approach for extracting privilege assignment to DB user accounts.

In fact, I presented three different methods to do just that and extensively review the performance and resource impacts of each approach.